# CPT post doesnt shows tags and category on backend admin page

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-query

Few days ago updated my wordpress(on local host) to 4.8, on update the categories and tags for cpt post which has assigned 'hierarchical=> true' for using 'page-attributes' has stopped displaying on admin panel of wordpress backend even though it has assigned respective tags,cities and categories to individual post.

As we have page-attributes assigned to CPT for which we have set hierarchical as true, making true its showing tags and category columns as blank in admin panel which shows in below image

[image]

This used to work well before the update to version 4.8.

we have registered the cpt using belowed code.

```
function register_post_types(){
$singular = 'Post';
$plural = 'Pages';
register_post_type( 'XXXX', [
'has_archive' => TRUE,
'hierarchical' => true,
'singular_name' => $singular,
'labels' => [
    'name' => 'XXXX'
],
'public' => TRUE,
'supports' => ['editor', 'page-attributes', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'title','custom-fields','excerpt'],
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
] );
add_image_size( 'YYYY', 650, 650, TRUE );
}
add_action( 'init', __NAMESPACE__.'\register_post_types', 20 );
```

In the above code we tried changing 'hierarchical' => false, which shows the data in following tags and category columns but on edit individual post the page-attributes option gets changed to post-attributes which disables the parent post.

For example see below image:

[image]

As on making hierarchiocal=>false we get post-attributes displayed instead of page-attributes and not showing parent option to select in individual post.

**I tried multiple of changes to make it work but no luck!!**

Even on googling not got expected results.

Do I need to add something else to make it work?

Thanks a lot for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

You havent registered the taxonomy, example of one I use

```
register_taxonomy( 'location', 
        array('business'), /* if you change the name of register_post_type( 'custom_type', then you have to change this */
        array('hierarchical' => true,     /* if this is true, it acts like categories */             
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Locations', 'custom' ), /* name of the custom taxonomy */
                'singular_name' => __( 'location', 'custom' ), /* single taxonomy name */
                'search_items' =>  __( 'Search locations', 'custom' ), /* search title for taxomony */
                'all_items' => __( 'All Locations', 'custom' ), /* all title for taxonomies */
                'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Location ', 'custom' ), /* parent title for taxonomy */
                'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent location:', 'custom' ), /* parent taxonomy title */
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Custom Category', 'custom' ), /* edit custom taxonomy title */
                'update_item' => __( 'Update Custom Category', 'custom' ), /* update title for taxonomy */
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Custom Category', 'custom' ), /* add new title for taxonomy */
                'new_item_name' => __( 'New Custom Category Name', 'custom' ) /* name title for taxonomy */
            ),
            'show_admin_column' => true, 
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'location' ),
        )
    );
```

Comment: you can check above i have updated the question, on making hierarchical=> false it works but page-attributes doesnt work on it and we need page-attributes to be work.